# What is the 'right' derivative of a scalar field such that the volume integral gives back the original scalar field.

Tags: integration, derivatives, physics

edit: from Sangchul Lee's comments, it appears my definition was initially inaccurate so it has been corrected. In physics one finds the following definition of the action density:

$$
\mathcal{S}[\Delta t,\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z]=\int_{\Delta z}\int_{\Delta y}\int_{\Delta z}\int_{\Delta t} \mathcal{L}[t,x,y,z]dtdxdydz
$$

Here, as a challenge, I am interested in defining the same concept but in the reverse direction:

$$
\mathcal{L}[t,x,y,z] = D[\mathcal{S}[\Delta t,\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z]]
$$

where $D$ is a suitable derivative, and where $\Delta t,\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z$ are pairs of real numbers.

---

What is $D$ in this case? If I take the total derivative I do not get the 4-form differential such $dtdxdydz$. If I instead take the gradient, then $\mathcal{L}$ is a vector, however, it must be a scalar. Finally, the last candidate I know is the directional derivative which produces a scalar --- So, is the Lagrangian the directional derivative of the action (the dependence on a path seems awfully specific)?

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance on Langrangian formulation, but how does the integral $$\iiiint \mathcal{L}[t,x,y,z]\,\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$$ still become a function of variables $t,x,y,z$, if the integral is taken over a fixed region (i.e., if the integral is 'definite')? I believe that understanding how this integral is formulated to give an action as a function of variables $t, x, y, z$ will help understand how to formulate $D$.

Comment: I'm still confused by your definition of an action. Usually the Lagragian is a functional, depending on some set of fields $\{\phi^a\}_{a\in I}$, its derivatives and spacetime. For various reasons, the Lagragian usually doesn't even depend explicitly on the spacetime coordinates (at least in simple examples). Could you maybe give a reference from where you got this definition?